# Using query for a specific date

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, database, sql

I am trying to pull data from SENT data view based on date. What format of date should I use?

I have tried this but no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate = '2017-05-29'
```

I have tried this but no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate = '05-29-2017'
```

Tried this too but no results:

```
SELECT *
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate =  '5/29/2017'
```

Looking at the data extension, the data seems be in this format "Tuesday, May 29, 2017 7:02 AM"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EventDate is a datetime - "2017-05-30 22:35:27.122" which is not the same as "2017-05-30" (midnight on 30th May). Try evaluating against:

cast(EventDate As Date)

This truncates EventDate so you're comparing like for like...

WHERE cast(EventDate As Date) = cast('2017-05-29' as Date)

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation article [Query: Find Subscribers by Date or Time Frame](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/query_find_subscribers_by_date_or_time_frame/) the date format to use is `'YYYY-MM-DD'` so in your case `'2017-05-29'` should be correct.

However in the documentation on [Data View: Sent](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_sent/) it is mentioned to be a datetime-value. As in the background Transact-SQL is used, you could cast the value with added time in your SQL-statement and therefore need to use a range from 00:00 to 24:00. Here you can find some examples: [datetime (Transact-SQL) - Examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql#examples)

```
SELECT *
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate between CAST('2017-05-29 00:00:00.000' AS datetime) AND CAST('2017-05-29 24:00:00.000' AS datetime)
```

Another option would be using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CAST(EventDate AS Date) = '2017-05-29'
```

Comment: You wrap it in quotes? Interesting.

Comment: At least that's how it is written in the marketing cloud documentation article I referred to.

Comment: I have tried this query already but getting no result (we have one mailing that went out on May 29, 2017 , I am looking at it on tracking page) `SELECT *
FROM _Sent WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate = '2017-05-29'`

Comment: Markus - I tested your second option as well and it worked WHERE CAST(EventDate AS Date) = '2017-05-29' . Thank you!